# ICU BreakIterator with Japanese

Tags: icu

I noticed BreakIterator with locales "en_Us" and "ja_JP" behaves differently even though the documentation says both break rules are now same. Am I wrong here?

"りんご is a fruit" is the test case that I used. This is breaking on every character for the japanese script in "en_US" locale but works as expected in "ja_JP" locale. If I am using "ja_JP" whether it will work in all other languages? what should I use to make it multilingual supported.

```
UErrorCode status = U_ZERO_ERROR;
UText *ut = utext_openUTF8(NULL, gUTF8Str, -1, &status);
BreakIterator* boundary = BreakIterator::createWordInstance("ja_JP", status);
boundary->setText(ut, status);
int pos_1 = ubrk_first(&bi);
int pos_2 = ubrk_next(&bi);
while (pos_2 != -1) {
   //printf text
   pos_1 = pos_2;
   pos_2 = ubrk_next(&bi);
}
```

I am using ICU 4.8.

Comment: Which documentation says they are the same?

Comment: @Steven May be I am wrong, somewhere I read from 4.8 onwards it is common and based on http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr29/. Is "ja_JP" is a super set of en_US rules? whether "ja_JP" BreakIterator will work  for all other languages?

Comment: @Stevan: for another question you answered like "You might break the string apart by script (uchar.h) and then run a
break over each script run ", Can you guide me here with example/documentation?

Comment: sorry did not check back here.  You can use this function, uscript_getScript http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/uscript_8h.html#a58e91e4b9ea0c12fc96415691f32f3a4 to determine the script of each section.

Comment: @Steven: How can we map a UScriptCode code to a locale? OR we need to use default locale for each script? whether default will solve this?

Comment: ulocdata_getExemplarSet will give you the chars used by a particular locale http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/ulocdata_8h.html#ae8930500be4571878f16aef1cf731cc1    - you can analyze those chars to see which script they belong to.